# Last Adobe Premiere Pro version for Windows 7

Tags: premiere, adobe, windows, adobe-media-encoder

Due to my hardware limitations, I'm forced to use Win7 instead of Win10.

On my current version of Adobe Premiere Pro, I can't attach and work with proxies.

I want to try newer version, but not the latest, since it's not supported by Win7.

Can you tell me the latest version of Adobe Premiere Pro which is still working under Win7 ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Version (CC 2019) 13.1.5.47  is the only version that installs on Windows 7,8,10
Good luck